# Conversion of large character array to integer in C

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, large-data

I'm looking for a way to convert a very large character array to an integer. For reference, I need to be able to convert a character array holding a number as big as: `1718944270642558716715` to an integer value.

How do I accomplish this please?
I've tried using `atoi()` but it returns -1.
I also tried using `atol()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoumax()` all with no luck.

**NOTE:** My code is to confirm with `-std=gnu89` so that puts the long long type out of the question. Your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of this number? What will you use it for? Perhaps it's better to keep it as characters, and work on the individual digits themselves for your operations?

Comment: Also, `int` is usually 32-bits, which means it can hold numbers from around negative two billion to up to plus two billion. The common integer sizes and their max/min values should have been covered by any decent beginners book, tutorial or class.

Comment: The biggest 64 bit positive signed number is 9223372036854775807 which is smaller than the number you want to convert to integer.

Comment: Okay, so, basically I'm reading numbers from the lines of a file and I need to perform arithmetic operations on these numbers. I'm using fgets to read each line in the file into a character array `char line_val[]`, that's why I need each string converted to a number.

Comment: there are large integer libraries such as gmp

Comment: So how can I go around it in this case? @urutech

Comment: @stark My code will be run on a hosted server and I'm not allowed to install any dependency.

Comment: You either use a larger integer library as @Stark suggested and is recommended or implement enough of something similar enough that will meet your needs. You are beyond the limits of built in types. Use a library built for the purpose or come up with enough of an implementation of your own.

Comment: I am yet to find one good reason why code should conform to a 34 year old standard.

Comment: The number 1718944270642558716715 requires 71 bits for a binary representation.  Few compilers support integer types that big, because there is no standard C integer type that big.  So you can't manipulate numbers like that as built-in integers.  You are going to have to use a "bignum" library such as GMP.  If you're not allowed to use any external libraries, you're going to have to write your own.  This is a fun, interesting, but challenging project.  Which operations will you have to perform on these numbers?

Comment: @Haris his teacher learned the language 30y ago and he is teaching since, not willing to learn something new

Comment: @SteveSummit I am to find the factors of the number

Comment: @EnweremMelvin Well, I can tell you exactly how hard this will be to do, because I wrote my own bignum library once, and among other things it knows how to factor big numbers, so I can tell you that the answer (in this case) is 5 × 7 × 29 × 10771 × 157231561910911.  But it took me months or years to get that library working well — it is not an easy task.  But, as I said, it's a great and instructive challenge.  We're not going to be able to tell you here everything you need to know to write the code — but it's a well-studied problem; there's plenty of literature out there.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read the Wikipedia article on [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: You could switch to Python which is large integer support built in.

Answer (score 2):

If you use gcc you can use `__int128` type. But you need to write most the functions yourself.

Example using your number:

```
__int128 atoi128(const char *str, int *err)
{
    __int128 result = 0;

    if(err) *err = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        if(isdigit((unsigned char)*str)) 
        {
            result *= 10;
            result += *str - '0';
            str++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(err) *err = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void printi128(__int128 val)
{
    if(val < 10) printf("%d", val);
    else 
    {
        printi128(val / 10);
        printf("%d", abs(val % 10));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    __int128 i;

    i = atoi128("9223372036854775807", NULL);
    printi128(i);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/znPde51jK